# Get neomake to recognize python and gcc location

Tags: spacevim, plugin-neomake

I installed the latest versions of Python and GCC/G++ in alternative locations. I am using SpaceVim. I think SpaceVim is using neomake as the default. I want to know how you can configure neomake to use the newest versions I installed in the alternative locations instead of the default version that was installed on linux. Also, I am trying to test c++17. Since c++17 is not the default, how would you be able to switch to that version with neomake?

Comment: Hi Rebecca, welcome to [vi.se]! I have a couple of suggestions for you to help you and others find your answer. (1) try running `:help neomake`—most plugins ship with documentation that you can read online. As a bonus, the internal vim doc is *amazing* (run `:help` and try the user manual, just for a spin). The neomake help should show configuration options. (2) most seasoned folks here will recommend against SpaceVim for reasons including this situation: it’s just too dang hard to know what’s going on when you need to do something yourself {cont...}

Comment: ... It turns out to be far easier long term to craft your own configuration, because then you know what plugins you have, what you need and dont, and you know the core of vim better (because you spend the time learning and honing it, rather than fighting against a distribution to let you do what you need). Good luck, and happy vimming!

Comment: What about setting `$CXX` and/or `$CXXFLAGS`?

Answer (score 1):

SpaceVim uses neomake by default: to  make neomake support this feature, you can  create a  `.clang`  file in the root of your project. Please read the [`lang#c`](https://spacevim.org/layers/lang/c/) layer doc.

Comment: The community usually discourages answers that are (mostly) links—it would be helpful if you could include more substantive information (even quotes from the link) to flesh out the answer.